# Duvida Volley em Android

Tags: android, web-service, volley

É necessário ter um ListView para enviar dados para o webservice com o Volley no Android? 
Pois apenas criei três EditText para testar. Está retornando **"erro Timeout"**.

Já verifiquei a url, está correta. Estou a dias tentando fazer isto, não estou conseguindo. Por isso estou recorrendo ajuda aqui.

Vou postar todo o código aqui:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {
    private EditText codigoCurso, nomeCurso, categoriaCurso, professorCurso;
    private Button botaoCadastrar;
    //Essa variavel sera utiliziada para solicitar as requisiçõies via Json
    RequestQueue request;
    //Serve para armazenar os dados
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectReq;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        codigoCurso = findViewById(R.id.editCodigo);
        nomeCurso = findViewById(R.id.editNomeCurso);
        categoriaCurso =findViewById(R.id.editCategoria);
        professorCurso = findViewById(R.id.editProfessor);
        botaoCadastrar = findViewById(R.id.btCadastrar);

        //Instanciando o objeto e informando que ele receberá asrequisições do Volley.
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    }

    //Todo método que é chamado por um button precisar ter View como parametro
    public void carregarWebService(View view) {

        String url = "http://192.168.xxx.x/webservices/registro.php?nome="+ nomeCurso.getText().toString() +"&categoria="+ categoriaCurso.getText().toString() +"&professor="+ professorCurso.getText().toString() + "" ;

        //é necessário substituir os espaços em branco que vem na url, senão da erro
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");

        /* Lendo a url */
        jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);

            request.add(jsonObjectReq);


    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Não foi possível conectar ao servidor",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cadastrado com sucesso!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        codigoCurso.setText("");
        nomeCurso.setText("");
        categoriaCurso.setText("");
        professorCurso.setText("");
        botaoCadastrar.setText("");
    }
}
```

Eu acredito que essa linha pode estar com erro:

```
jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
```

Pois não tenho uma lista no meu formulario, apenas EditTex. Pode ser feito dessa forma?

Testei a url manualmente o webservice está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Onde está o web service, na sua máquina local? O aplicativo está rodando em um dispositivo real ou emulador?

Comment: O webservice está rodando no xampp, com  php, no meu notebook. Estou testando no meu celular conectado ao cabo usb.

Comment: O celular deve estar conectado a mesma rede, sendo que o ip de acesso deve ser o ipv4 do seu notebook.

Comment: Eu peguei o ipv4 do meu pc, eu estive reparando em alguns tutoriais em percebi que depois do ipv4, algumas pessoas utilizam a porta , tipo 8080. Ou seja na url, logo após informar o ipv4, é inserido assim: ":8080". Seria isso o que esta faltando?

Comment: Eu sugiro você utilizar alguma ferramenta para testar seu servidor antes, onde você consiga inserir o ip, porta, passar todos os parâmetros para depois replicar no seu aplicativo Android. Um software bastante utilizado para isto é o Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/), bem fácil de usar.

Comment: Ja testei, inclusive ele esta rodando no servidor online, o problema esta no modo offline (localhost)

Comment: Como é o retorno da sua requisição, teria como postar aqui?